# Java blobstore method completeMultipartUpload throw null pointer exception for checkNotNull

Tags: java, intellij-idea, blobstore

I have a problem with saving .csv files by multi parts. In this part of the code:

```
@Override
public String completeMultipartUpload(MultipartUpload mpu, List<MultipartPart> parts) {
  ImmutableList.Builder<Blob> blobs = ImmutableList.builder();
  long contentLength = 0;
  Hasher md5Hasher = Hashing.md5().newHasher();

  for (MultipartPart part : parts) {
     Blob blobPart = getBlob(mpu.containerName(), MULTIPART_PREFIX + mpu.id() + "-" + mpu.blobName() + "-" + part.partNumber());
     contentLength += blobPart.getMetadata().getContentMetadata().getContentLength();
     blobs.add(blobPart);
     md5Hasher.putBytes(BaseEncoding.base16().lowerCase().decode(blobPart.getMetadata().getETag()));
  }
```

The problem occurs on my computer, the program works for other people. Namely, for a given part of the code, `blobPart.getMetadata().GetETag()` always for the first 9 parts work fine. And for part 10 and each subsequent part does return a null value for ETag, which then causes an error NullPointerException.
All `List<MultipartPart> parts` are adding in the same way. All have correct property.

I think it is problem with my Environment. I tried:

- reinstall IntelliJ
- reinstall Java/use a different version
- remove all libraries and install again

Or maybe something with encoding?
Other people for which it works are from another country, and I can see there is `BaseEncoding.base16()`?

StackTrace:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null
> at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:878)
> at com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding$StandardBaseEncoding.trimTrailingPadding(BaseEncoding.java:676)
> at com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding.decodeChecked(BaseEncoding.java:231)
> at com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding.decode(BaseEncoding.java:217)
> at org.jclouds.blobstore.config.LocalBlobStore.completeMultipartUpload(LocalBlobStore.java:843)

Answer (score 0):

I hit perfectly the limit of the path length for windows, it threw an error because the path passed to
`UserDefinedFileAttributeView view = getUserDefinedFileAttributeView(file.toPath());` it was too long.